# R function or package to perform Q-mode factor analysis

Tags: r, factor-analysis

I am performing factor analysis of several matrices (each one of them represents a location), which include several cases (rows) and several measured variables (columns), with factanal(). With this, I can study how the *variables* distribute on a factor biplot. Now I want to use the "Q-mode" (such as in Statistica) to study how all the *cases* (e.g. rows) of all matrices are distributed in a factor biplot. Is there an R function / package to do that?

I have been searching and found the "qrfactor" package, but it has been removed from RCRAN, and I do not know if it is reliable.